# Algebras over endo-profunctors

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory

I am currently trying to work out algebras over profunctors/distributors, which I first stumbled upon on the [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebra+for+a+profunctor). However the nlab page does not provide external references. Can anyone point me to lecture notes or papers that would be relevant?

Comment: According to https://ncatlab.org/nlab/history/algebra+for+a+profunctor and https://nforum.ncatlab.org/discussion/815/algebra-for-a-cc-bimodule/, the page was created by (someone with the same name as) @SridharRamesh, so he might be most likely to be able to answer your question.